# TextView глючит на старых версиях Android и в теме Holo

Tags: android

Написал программу на стандартной теме... Всё работает! Теперь решил поменять тему на Holo. Поменял и оказалось что на одном сотике у меня всё норм, а на старом - TextView отображается криво - не работает перенос строки...

Это как-нибудь лечиться?

Comment: покажите хотя бы скрин

Comment: "Хотя бы" - мало сказано. Пусть ТС хоть скажет, каким образом он достал Ноlo для старого телефона.

И да, ждём тех, кто снова отреагирует на слово "***сотик***" :)

Comment: @SuperCreeper мы просто все отстали от жизни ─ на не понять радости кодить на кортах в кепке и вытряхивать из клавиатуры  семки.

Comment: Разобрался - Holo просто не работает для старых версий))) Поэтому, для старых версий использую другую схему)